# Why the swift throws exception despite "try?"

Tags: ios, swift

I found some crashes in my app despite of `try?` construction. The firebase crashlytics logged

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
Invalid number value (infinite) in JSON write
```

Here is a test example

```
        let avgSpeed = 0.1 / 0
        print(avgSpeed)
        let data = ["average_speed" : avgSpeed]
        if let body = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [data]) {
            print("success")
        } else {
            print("unable to make body for call")
        }
```

Why did that happen?

iOS 13, swift 4

Comment: this particular exception was thrown by `Foundation Kit` – usually Swift cannot catch _exceptions_, Swift can catch _errors_ only.

Comment: It seems that the exception is thrown by the *evil* division by zero.

Comment: @vadian The division by zero is legal (it returns `Double.infinity`). That just can't be encoded into JSON (which causes JSONSerialization to throw an exception). I assume the OP intentionally created this situation to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`try?` does not catch exceptions. It catches thrown errors. Those are different things in Swift. Exceptions are at the Objective-C level and cannot be caught by Swift at all (they can't be *safely* caught in ObjC in most cases either, but that's a different discussion).

The solution in this case is to use JSONEncoder rather than JSONSerialization. JSONEncoder is a pure-Swift system. JSONSerialization is bridged from ObjC.

```
let body = try? JSONEncoder().encode([data])
```

See [Handling Errors](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) for more information:

> Error handling in Swift resembles exception handling in other languages, with the use of the try, catch and throw keywords. Unlike exception handling in many languages—including Objective-C—error handling in Swift does not involve unwinding the call stack, a process that can be computationally expensive. As such, the performance characteristics of a throw statement are comparable to those of a return statement.

If you want to use JSONSerialization, it's important to recognize that it is a programming error to call it this way. The exception is *intended* to crash the program (even in ObjC). The correct way to write this code is:

```
if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject([data]), // <=== first, check it is valid
    let body = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [data]) {
    print("success")
} else {
    print("unable to make body for call")
}
```

See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data) for more information:

> If obj will not produce valid JSON, an exception is thrown. This exception is thrown prior to parsing and represents a programming error, not an internal error. You should check whether the input will produce valid JSON before calling this method by using isValidJSONObject(_:).

The thrown error from JSONSerialization is only to indicate an *internal* error in the serializer, not an attempt to encode an invalid object:

> **error**
>
> If an internal error occurs, upon return contains an NSError object with code NSPropertyListWriteInvalidError that describes the problem.